# Why I'm getting duplicate records when the entity is updated using EntityManager merge() method?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm having an issue where duplicate record is created in the database when I update the entity object returned after the calling `entityManager.persist()`.

This is what's happening. I'm persisting an entity and using the same object to apply some changes. When I run `merge()` to update the entity it results in two records in the database.

Both records have almost identical data but only the record with higher id (I'm using an autogenerated integer as id) has the values updated after calling the `persist()` method.

Any help on how to avoid this? What really need to do is to update the same record with new values. I cannot use `em.getTransaction()` within the `create()` method since I am using a JTA data source. I tried to use `UserTransaction` but it's also not possible here.

This is how the code is organized in my application.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="table_name")
public class EntityClass{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    //more fields

    //getters and setters
} 

@Stateless
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.MANDATORY)
public class ClassA{
    @PersistanceContext
    EntityManager em;

    public <T> T create(T t){
        em.persist(t)
        return t;
    }

    public <T> T update(T t){
        return (T) em.merge(t);
    }
}

@Stateless
public class ClassB{
    @EJB
    ClassA a;

    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void createEntity(...){
        EntityClass ec = new EntityClass();

        //more operations where I set ec values

        ec = a.create(ec)

        internalMethod(ec)
    }

    private void internalMethod(EntityClass ec, ...){
        //some more operations altering ec values

        //after this I'm left with two records with different id's and
        //only the record with higher id has the updated data
        a.update(ec);
    }

}
```

Comment: So what if you call `merge`. It all comes down to whether the object is detached that you pass in. Is it?

Comment: Do you have any ´@TransactionAttribute´ annotations on ´ClassA´ or its super types?

Comment: What happens if you comment out the last line, `a.update(ec)`? Do you have one or two records in the database? And if its one, does it contain the changes from only before or also from after the create method?

Comment: @Meini Actually yes. I've updated the code in the question with it.

Comment: @Bernhard I'm left with one record without the changes made after the create() method